# Why we need rules method in YII?

Tags: php, yii

I am little bit confuse about rules method in yii framework. Here is a rules function from sample blog application.

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('title, content, status, author_id', 'required'),
        array('status, create_time, update_time, author_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('title', 'length', 'max'=>128),
        array('tags', 'safe'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, title, content, tags, status, create_time, update_time, author_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

- Why we need this method in our class?
- How to use it effectively?
- Where does it help us? In validating forms ???
- Any one can explain HOW it works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> These rules are applied by the CModel::validate() method which returns
>   a boolean value. By default, the method CActiveRecord::save()
>   automatically calls this validation, and requires it to succeed before
>   it tries to save the record.

[Reference: Model rules validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/)

Comment: thanks for answer. Can we add own validations to it? if so, how to do it?

Comment: Yes of cause, [Create your own Validation Rule](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/)

Answer (score 2):

Yii is a framework that adopt MVC pattern. M, in MVC stands for Model. That's means that all stuffs related to the data, are located in Model classes. Type of fields, ruls, relations, ... Rules, regard date, so you'll find it in Model classes.

In particular Yii uses model methods when creating a form (couse form are generated for data). Yii use model when validate data. Yii uses model when you need to validate some particular fields like email, date, password and so on.

It help us because because you dont need anytime to implement validation rules for email. A field must be only a number? An Email? A Date? An Url? Must be unique in entire model? Yii provides [a lot of validators](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/tree/master/framework/validators) for us.

Also, you can [create your own validator rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/).

Answer (score 0):

It will allow you to save a lot of time and lines of code when you do development and need to verify data (in most of the cases - "user data").

Yii comes with good docs and wiki. I will add one more [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules) in addition to listed above, which can help you to understand what it is and how to cook it.